# How to update a foreign key field in Django models.py?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Here is the source:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/

At the beginning, let's look at the models.py field:

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    mod_date = models.DateField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    n_comments = models.IntegerField()
    n_pingbacks = models.IntegerField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.headline
```

This is how, a row or an object is created of Blog type:

```
>>> from blog.models import Blog
>>> b = Blog(name='Beatles Blog', tagline='All the latest Beatles news.')
>>> b.save()
```

My question is how to update blog column/attribute of Entry object (which stores Foreign Key in relation to Blog) with the entry I created in Blog class?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First get the `Blog` object and then pass it to `Entry`.

```
b=Blog.objects.get(name='Beatles Blog', tagline='All the latest Beatles news.')

e=Entry(blog=b,headline='some headline',body_text='text here',....)
e.save()
```

Comment: @Asif, Have you tried this?? Did it worked for you?? If any problem let me know.

Comment: Well, it sure did. Thank you!
If you prefer economy of expression, you can write following line which will create the row and save it:
e=Entry.objects.create(blog=b,headline='some headline',body_text='text here',....)

Comment: @Asif, You can also use `update_or_create` if you need to create only when new records come or else update.

Comment: @Asif, If my solution helped you, please select the answer, thanks a lot for all the cooperation.

Comment: this helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You can use solution from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#topics-db-queries-update). Or short answer:

```
b = Blog.objects.get(pk=1)
Entry.objects.filter(pk=17).update(blog=b)
```

1. Need to select row/rows which you wanna update
2. Use function `update`

Comment: why you are taking `pk=1` and `pk=17`. I don't think this will help the person in understanding what he want to do.

Comment: @AstikAnand it just an example